# Google Maps API v3 and Phonegap: not visible in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to integrate a googlemap into a phonegap App with phonegap build. While the map is displaying correctly in android, I haven't been able to show it in iOS. I haven't experienced any issues when loading the page in a browser. I also successfully loaded the page in Safari on iOS

The API is not displayed at all (some other people had the issue that only the controls are showing)

the page with the map looks like this: http://app.markheuer.de/largemap_geoposition.html?type=Pflucken&address=Freiburg&useGeo=NO 
the code on that page is identical with the code I put in phonegap.

Many people solved this issue by whitelisting the google domains, but this didn't work for me. At the moment I am using `<access origin="*" />`, so the whitelist should not cause any problems.

Is there anything I am missing? Anything else that has to go into the config.xml?

Thanks for your help!

---

**edit:**
Here is the function I use for showing the map:

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById("addressInput").value = liste.address;
        var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.993943, 7.845411);
        var myOptions = {
            center: centerLatLng,
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
            }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
      prepareGeolocation();

      if (liste.useGeo == "YES") {
          doGeolocation();
      }
      else {
         searchLocations();
      }
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
      locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
      locationSelect.onchange = function() {
        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        if (markerNum != "none"){
          google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
        }
      };
   }
```

Here is the html:
      
and css

```
#map { 
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
background: red; }
```

Obviously, the whole code is much longer, I think it would compromise the readibility of the thread if I post it. But you can of course click the link above, and view the whole source code.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to display the map?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added some code. Is there anything specific that would be of interest?